# How to paint on a video frame by frame and save it using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ffmpeg, video-editing

The goal is to analyse a video frame by frame and apply a painting on each of those frames. Then save the video and be able to play it.

Do you know if such a thing is possible in flutter? I've heard about ffmpeg package but I'm not too sure if that's possible with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make this implementation on respective platforms. It will be more performant that way and you can get complete control of the video generation.

on iOS : `AVMutableComposition` class is the way to go

I don't know about android.